# @cyntler/react-doc-viewer get LocalFiles in React

Tags: reactjs

I try to get use React DocViewer...

here is my component :

```
<DocViewer 
                documents={doc}
                pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers}
                config={{
                    header: {
                    disableHeader: true,
                    disableFileName: true,
                    retainURLParams: true,
                    },
                    csvDelimiter: ';', // "," as default,
                    pdfZoom: {
                    defaultZoom: .1, // 1 as default,
                    zoomJump: 1, // 0.1 as default,
                    },
                    pdfVerticalScrollByDefault: false, // false as default
                }}
                onClose={this.handleClose}
            />
```

and my Links:

```
const doc = [{ uri: "/bbbb.xlsx" }]; NOT WORK
const doc = [{ uri: "/ccccc.pdf" }]; WORKS
const doc = [{ uri: "https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/bbbb.xlsx" }]; WORKS
```

Anyone have any idea and solution for that situation in react...(nextJs)

and also u can advicse me a better office docs viewer in React Library